# В битрикс 1с каталоге- пропадает компонент детального просмотра товара

Tags: битрикс

В битрикс 1с каталоге- пропадает компонент детального просмотра товара. В административной части все работает. Что может быть?  В настройках прав инфоблока уже смотрел, что может быть еще? Буду признателен любой помощи!

//шаблон компонента catalog.element

```
<?php
if (!defined('B_PROLOG_INCLUDED') || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die();

use Bitrix\Main\Localization\Loc;

/**
 * @global CMain $APPLICATION
 * @var array $arParams
 * @var array $arResult
 * @var CatalogSectionComponent $component
 * @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this
 * @var string $templateName
 * @var string $componentPath
 * @var string $templateFolder
 */

$this->setFrameMode(true);

$templateLibrary = array('popup', 'fx');
$currencyList = '';

if (!empty($arResult['CURRENCIES']))
{
    $templateLibrary[] = 'currency';
    $currencyList = CUtil::PhpToJSObject($arResult['CURRENCIES'], false, true, true);
}

$templateData = array(
    'TEMPLATE_THEME' => $arParams['TEMPLATE_THEME'],
    'TEMPLATE_LIBRARY' => $templateLibrary,
    'CURRENCIES' => $currencyList,
    'ITEM' => array(
        'ID' => $arResult['ID'],
        'IBLOCK_ID' => $arResult['IBLOCK_ID'],
        'OFFERS_SELECTED' => $arResult['OFFERS_SELECTED'],
        'JS_OFFERS' => $arResult['JS_OFFERS']
    )
);
unset($currencyList, $templateLibrary);

$mainId = $this->GetEditAreaId($arResult['ID']);
$itemIds = array(
    'ID' => $mainId,
    'DISCOUNT_PERCENT_ID' => $mainId.'_dsc_pict',
    'STICKER_ID' => $mainId.'_sticker',
    'BIG_SLIDER_ID' => $mainId.'_big_slider',
    'BIG_IMG_CONT_ID' => $mainId.'_bigimg_cont',
    'SLIDER_CONT_ID' => $mainId.'_slider_cont',
    'BLOCK_PRICE_OLD' => $mainId.'_block_price',
    'OLD_PRICE_ID' => $mainId.'_old_price',
    'PRICE_ID' => $mainId.'_price',
    'DISCOUNT_PRICE_ID' => $mainId.'_price_discount',
    'PRICE_TOTAL' => $mainId.'_price_total',
    'SLIDER_CONT_OF_ID' => $mainId.'_slider_cont_',
    'SLIDER_PAGER_OF_ID' => $mainId.'_slider_pager_',
    'QUANTITY_COUNTER_ID' => $mainId.'_counter',
    'QUANTITY_ID' => $mainId.'_quantity',
    'QUANTITY_DOWN_ID' => $mainId.'_quant_down',
    'QUANTITY_UP_ID' => $mainId.'_quant_up',
    'QUANTITY_MEASURE' => $mainId.'_quant_measure',
    'QUANTITY_MEASURE_CONTAINER' => $mainId.'_quant_measure_container',
    'QUANTITY_LIMIT' => $mainId.'_quant_limit',
    'BUY_LINK' => $mainId.'_buy_link',
    'ADD_BASKET_LINK' => $mainId.'_add_basket_link',
    'BASKET_ACTIONS_ID' => $mainId.'_basket_actions',
    'NOT_AVAILABLE_MESS' => $mainId.'_not_avail',
    'COMPARE_LINK' => $mainId.'_compare_link',
    'TREE_ID' => $mainId.'_skudiv',
    'DISPLAY_PROP_DIV' => $mainId.'_sku_prop',
    'DESCRIPTION_ID' => $mainId.'_description',
    'DISPLAY_MAIN_PROP_DIV' => $mainId.'_main_sku_prop',
    'OFFER_GROUP' => $mainId.'_set_group_',
    'BASKET_PROP_DIV' => $mainId.'_basket_prop',
    'SUBSCRIBE_LINK' => $mainId.'_subscribe',
    'TABS_ID' => $mainId.'_tabs',
    'TAB_CONTAINERS_ID' => $mainId.'_tab_containers',
    'SMALL_CARD_PANEL_ID' => $mainId.'_small_card_panel',
    'TABS_PANEL_ID' => $mainId.'_tabs_panel'
);
$obName = $templateData['JS_OBJ'] = 'ob'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', 'x', $mainId);
$name = !empty($arResult['IPROPERTY_VALUES']['ELEMENT_PAGE_TITLE'])
    ? $arResult['IPROPERTY_VALUES']['ELEMENT_PAGE_TITLE']
    : $arResult['NAME'];
$title = !empty($arResult['IPROPERTY_VALUES']['ELEMENT_DETAIL_PICTURE_FILE_TITLE'])
    ? $arResult['IPROPERTY_VALUES']['ELEMENT_DETAIL_PICTURE_FILE_TITLE']
    : $arResult['NAME'];
$alt = !empty($arResult['IPROPERTY_VALUES']['ELEMENT_DETAIL_PICTURE_FILE_ALT'])
    ? $arResult['IPROPERTY_VALUES']['ELEMENT_DETAIL_PICTURE_FILE_ALT']
    : $arResult['NAME'];

$haveOffers = !empty($arResult['OFFERS']);
if ($haveOffers)
{
    $actualItem = $arResult['OFFERS'][$arResult['OFFERS_SELECTED']] ?? reset($arResult['OFFERS']);
    $showSliderControls = false;

    foreach ($arResult['OFFERS'] as $offer)
    {
        if ($offer['MORE_PHOTO_COUNT'] > 1)
        {
            $showSliderControls = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    $actualItem = $arResult;
    $showSliderControls = $arResult['MORE_PHOTO_COUNT'] > 1;
}
$percent = '';
if (!empty($actualItem['MORE_PHOTO']))
{
    $firstPhoto = reset($actualItem['MORE_PHOTO']);
    $percent  = ($firstPhoto['HEIGHT']/$firstPhoto['WIDTH'])*100;
    $percent  = ($percent > 160) ? 160 : $percent;
    $percent = 'padding-top: '.$percent.'%;';
    unset($firstPhoto);
}

$skuProps = array();
$price = $actualItem['ITEM_PRICES'][$actualItem['ITEM_PRICE_SELECTED']];
$measureRatio = $actualItem['ITEM_MEASURE_RATIOS'][$actualItem['ITEM_MEASURE_RATIO_SELECTED']]['RATIO'];
$showDiscount = $price['PERCENT'] > 0;

if ($arParams['SHOW_SKU_DESCRIPTION'] === 'Y')
{
    $skuDescription = false;
    foreach ($arResult['OFFERS'] as $offer)
    {
        if ($offer['DETAIL_TEXT'] != '' || $offer['PREVIEW_TEXT'] != '')
        {
            $skuDescription = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    $showDescription = $skuDescription || !empty($arResult['PREVIEW_TEXT']) || !empty($arResult['DETAIL_TEXT']);
}
else
{
    $showDescription = !empty($arResult['PREVIEW_TEXT']) || !empty($arResult['DETAIL_TEXT']);
}
$showBuyBtn = in_array('BUY', $arParams['ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION']);
$buyButtonClassName = in_array('BUY', $arParams['ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION_PRIMARY']) ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-link';
$showAddBtn = in_array('ADD', $arParams['ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION']);
$showButtonClassName = in_array('ADD', $arParams['ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION_PRIMARY']) ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-link';
$showSubscribe = $arParams['PRODUCT_SUBSCRIPTION'] === 'Y' && ($arResult['PRODUCT']['SUBSCRIBE'] === 'Y' || $haveOffers);

$arParams['MESS_BTN_BUY'] = $arParams['MESS_BTN_BUY'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCE_CATALOG_BUY');
$arParams['MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET'] = $arParams['MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCE_CATALOG_ADD');
$arParams['MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE'] = $arParams['MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCE_CATALOG_NOT_AVAILABLE');
$arParams['MESS_BTN_COMPARE'] = $arParams['MESS_BTN_COMPARE'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCE_CATALOG_COMPARE');
$arParams['MESS_PRICE_RANGES_TITLE'] = $arParams['MESS_PRICE_RANGES_TITLE'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCE_CATALOG_PRICE_RANGES_TITLE');
$arParams['MESS_DESCRIPTION_TAB'] = $arParams['MESS_DESCRIPTION_TAB'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCE_CATALOG_DESCRIPTION_TAB');
$arParams['MESS_PROPERTIES_TAB'] = $arParams['MESS_PROPERTIES_TAB'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCE_CATALOG_PROPERTIES_TAB');
$arParams['MESS_COMMENTS_TAB'] = $arParams['MESS_COMMENTS_TAB'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCE_CATALOG_COMMENTS_TAB');
$arParams['MESS_SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY'] = $arParams['MESS_SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCE_CATALOG_SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY');
$arParams['MESS_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_MANY'] = $arParams['MESS_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_MANY'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCE_CATALOG_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_MANY');
$arParams['MESS_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_FEW'] = $arParams['MESS_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_FEW'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCE_CATALOG_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_FEW');

$themeClass = isset($arParams['TEMPLATE_THEME']) ? ' bx-'.$arParams['TEMPLATE_THEME'] : '';
?>
<div style="display:block;" class="product-detail   row <?=$themeClass?>" id="<?=$itemIds['ID']?>">
    <section class="item_intro_section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                        "bitrix:breadcrumb",
                        "mainbread",
                        Array(
                            "PATH" => "",
                            "SITE_ID" => "s1",
                            "START_FROM" => "0"
                        )
                    );?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row flex box item_intro_flex">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="item_text1">серия VENTURA <?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['SERIES_LABEL']['VALUE']?></div>
                    <div class="item_text2">
                        <h1><?=$arResult['NAME']?></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_text3">
                        <?=$arResult['PREVIEW_TEXT']?>
                    </div>

                    <a class="button"
                       id="<?=$itemIds['ADD_BASKET_LINK']?>"
                       href="javascript:void(0);">
                        добавить в корзину →
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="item_main_img">
                        <img src="<? echo($arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["SRC"]) ?>" alt="<? echo($arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["ALT"]) ?>">
                        <div class="scroll_img"><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/img/scroll.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="item_specification_section" id="<?=$itemIds['BIG_SLIDER_ID']?>">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2 class="itemh2">Сферы применения и особенности</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row flex box">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <ul class="item_hover_icons">
                        <?foreach($arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["SPHERES"]["VALUE"] as $SpheresSnap):?>
                            <?$res = CIBlockElement::GetByID($SpheresSnap)?>
                            <?if($ar_res = $res->GetNext())?>
                                <li data-text="<?=$ar_res["NAME"];?>" data-link="<? echo $ar_res['DETAIL_TEXT']?>">
                            <span><?php echo CFile::ShowImage($ar_res['DETAIL_PICTURE'], 32, 34, "border=0", "", true); ?></span>
                            </li>
                        <?endforeach;?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="item_icons">
                        <?foreach($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["ICON"]["VALUE"] as $val):?>
                            <div class="item_icon">
                                <? $src = CFile::GetPath($val); ?>
                                <img src="<?=$src; ?>" alt="">
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row tech_part">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2 class="itemh2">Технические характеристики</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row flex box">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h3 class="itemh3">Габаритные размеры</h3>
                    <a href="<?=CFile::GetPath($arResult['PROPERTIES']['DIMENSIONS_SCHEMA']['VALUE'])?>"  data-fancybox><img src="<?=CFile::GetPath($arResult['PROPERTIES']['DIMENSIONS_SCHEMA']['VALUE'])?>" alt="" class="schema_item"></a>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h3 class="itemh3">Технические данные</h3>
                    <?php
                    if (
                        $arResult['PREVIEW_TEXT'] != ''
                        && (
                            $arParams['DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT_MODE'] === 'S'
                            || ($arParams['DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT_MODE'] === 'E' && $arResult['DETAIL_TEXT'] == '')
                        )
                    )
                    {
                        echo $arResult['PREVIEW_TEXT_TYPE'] === 'html' ? $arResult['PREVIEW_TEXT'] : '<p>'.$arResult['PREVIEW_TEXT'].'</p>';
                    }

                    if ($arResult['DETAIL_TEXT'] != '')
                    {
                        echo $arResult['DETAIL_TEXT_TYPE'] === 'html' ? $arResult['DETAIL_TEXT'] : '<p>'.$arResult['DETAIL_TEXT'].'</p>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row documentation_wrp">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3 class="itemh3">Документация</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row flex box">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="<?=CFile::GetPath($arResult['PROPERTIES']['DOCUMENTATION_1']['VALUE'])?>" class="file_item_link"><?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['NAME_DOCUMENTATION_1']['VALUE']?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="<?=CFile::GetPath($arResult['PROPERTIES']['DOCUMENTATION_2']['VALUE'])?>" class="file_item_link"><?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['NAME_DOCUMENTATION_2']['VALUE']?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="<?=CFile::GetPath($arResult['PROPERTIES']['DOCUMENTATION_3']['VALUE'])?>" class="file_item_link"><?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['NAME_DOCUMENTATION_3']['VALUE']?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="<?=CFile::GetPath($arResult['PROPERTIES']['DOCUMENTATION_4']['VALUE'])?>" class="file_item_link"><?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['NAME_DOCUMENTATION_4']['VALUE']?></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row similar_list">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2 class="itemh2">Вам может подойти</h2>
                </div>
            </div>


            <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.section",
    "ventura_bootstrap_v4",
    Array(
        "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",
        "ADD_PICT_PROP" => "-",
        "ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET" => "Y",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
        "ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => "ADD",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "BACKGROUND_IMAGE" => "-",
        "BASKET_URL" => "/personal/basket.php",
        "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "COMPATIBLE_MODE" => "Y",
        "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N",
        "CUSTOM_FILTER" => "{\"CLASS_ID\":\"CondGroup\",\"DATA\":{\"All\":\"AND\",\"True\":\"True\"},\"CHILDREN\":[]}",
        "DISABLE_INIT_JS_IN_COMPONENT" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_COMPARE" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "RAND",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "RAND",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "RAND",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "RAND",
        "ENLARGE_PRODUCT" => "STRICT",
        "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
        "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
        "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE_OFFERS" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "4",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",
        "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
        "LABEL_PROP" => array(),
        "LAZY_LOAD" => "N",
        "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
        "LOAD_ON_SCROLL" => "N",
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET" => "В корзину",
        "MESS_BTN_BUY" => "Купить",
        "MESS_BTN_DETAIL" => "Подробнее",
        "MESS_BTN_LAZY_LOAD" => "Показать ещё",
        "MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE" => "Подписаться",
        "MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Нет в наличии",
        "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
        "OFFERS_LIMIT" => "5",
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Товары",
        "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "4",
        "PARTIAL_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => "N",
        "PRICE_CODE" => array(),
        "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y",
        "PRODUCT_BLOCKS_ORDER" => "price,props,sku,quantityLimit,quantity,buttons",
        "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",
        "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => "prop",
        "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => "quantity",
        "PRODUCT_ROW_VARIANTS" => "[{'VARIANT':'2','BIG_DATA':false},{'VARIANT':'2','BIG_DATA':false},{'VARIANT':'2','BIG_DATA':false},{'VARIANT':'2','BIG_DATA':false},{'VARIANT':'2','BIG_DATA':false},{'VARIANT':'2','BIG_DATA':false}]",
        "PRODUCT_SUBSCRIPTION" => "N",
        "PROPERTY_CODE_MOBILE" => array("SERIES_LABEL", "TEHN", "APPLICATIONS", "VOLTAGE", "CAPACITY", "LONG", "WIDTH", "HEIGHT", "WEIGHT", "OUTPUT_TYPE", "LIFE_TIME", "DIMENSIONS_SCHEMA", "NAME_DOCUMENTATION_1", "DOCUMENTATION_1", "NAME_DOCUMENTATION_2", "DOCUMENTATION_2", "NAME_DOCUMENTATION_3", "DOCUMENTATION_3", "NAME_DOCUMENTATION_4", "DOCUMENTATION_4", "RECOMMEND", "BLOG_COMMENTS_CNT", "SPHERES"),
        "RCM_PROD_ID" => $_REQUEST["PRODUCT_ID"],
        "RCM_TYPE" => "personal",
        "DETAIL_URL" => "/catalog/#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
        "SECTION_CODE_PATH" => $_REQUEST["SECTION_CODE_PATH"],
        "SECTION_ID" => "",
        "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",
        "SECTION_URL" => "/catalog/#SECTION_CODE#/",
        "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array("", ""),
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "SEF_RULE" => "#SECTION_CODE#",
        "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "Y",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
        "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "Y",
        "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "Y",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
        "SHOW_404" => "N",
        "SHOW_ALL_WO_SECTION" => "Y",
        "SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP" => "N",
        "SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT" => "N",
        "SHOW_FROM_SECTION" => "N",
        "SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY" => "N",
        "SHOW_OLD_PRICE" => "N",
        "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",
        "SHOW_SLIDER" => "N",
        "SLIDER_INTERVAL" => "3000",
        "SLIDER_PROGRESS" => "N",
        "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
        "USE_ENHANCED_ECOMMERCE" => "N",
        "USE_MAIN_ELEMENT_SECTION" => "N",
        "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",
        "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => "N",
        "SECTION_CODE" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_CODE"],
    )

);?>



            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><a href="/catalog/" class="button full_list">ПОКАЗАТЬ ПОЛНЫЙ СПИСОК →</a></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>



    <section class="usage_section item_usage_section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="h2_flex">
                        <h2 class="itemh2">Сферы применения</h2>
                        <div class="swiper_basic_controls">
                            <div class="control_prev"><img src="img/prev1.png" alt=""></div>
                            <div class="control_next"><img src="img/next1.png" alt=""></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="fullw">
                        <div class="swiper swiper_usage">
                            <div class="swiper-wrapper">

                                <?foreach($arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["SPHERES"]["VALUE"] as $SpheresSnap):?>
                                    <?$res = CIBlockElement::GetByID($SpheresSnap)?>
                                    <?if($ar_res = $res->GetNext())?>
                                        <div class="swiper-slide col3_wid">
                                            <a href="<? echo $ar_res['DETAIL_TEXT']?>" class="usage_elem">
                                                <div class="usage_img">
                                                    <?php echo CFile::ShowImage($ar_res['PREVIEW_PICTURE'], 325, 215, "border=0", "", false); ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <p class="usage_ttle"><?=$ar_res["NAME"];?></p>
                                                <p class="usage_text">
                                                    <? echo $ar_res['PREVIEW_TEXT']?>
                                                </p>

                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                <?endforeach;?>


                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="inner_contact_section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>Консультант <span>свяжется</span> с вами и <span>расскажет</span>  <br>
                        о преимуществах нашего оборудования</h2>
                    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                        "kontactcomp:main.feedback",
                        "callForm",
                        Array(
                            "AJAX_MODE" => "Y",
                            "EMAIL_TO" => "evgeniy.mudrov@akku-vertrieb.ru, info@ventura-battery.com",
                            "EVENT_MESSAGE_ID" => array("7"),
                            "OK_TEXT" => "Спасибо, ваше сообщение принято.",
                            "USE_CAPTCHA" => "N"
                        )
                    );?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</div>
```

Comment: Как понять "пропадает"?

Comment: Разметка пропадает, если посмотреть исходный код. А в админке есть

Comment: 1. Какой-нибудь незакрытый тег. 2. Кэширование - отдаётся старая страница.

Comment: @ВикторКарев Спасибо за помощь. Кеширование проверил много раз. А не закрытый тег не может быть, так как разметка вообще проподает

Comment: Попробуйте поставить $this->setFrameMode(false);

Comment: Попробовал, но эффект тот же

Comment: Тогда смотреть выше - место, где компонент вставляется. Вставлять отладочный вывод, проверять нет ли условий типа if($USER->IsAdmin())